# Python format string with offset

Tags: python, format, seaborn

I have a seaborn heatmap, and I am using `mpldatacursor` to show annotations on the squares, in this case, the x-axis coordinate: 
[image]

I am showing the hovering tooltip through the following line:

```
datacursor(hover=True, axes = self.axh, formatter = "Value: {x:.0f}".format)
```

The problem is, my data starts at 70, and the x-axis index of the heatmap starts from 0, which is why the value in the image is 7. What I was trying to do is to find some way to "add" an offset to the value, so that I would get the right value, which is 77. I tried the following:

`formatter = str(eval(str("{x:.0f}".format) + "70")).format`

But it doesn't work...how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
formatter = lambda **d: "Value: {:.0f}".format(d["x"] + 70)
```

So what the problem was before is that I didn't understand what should be provided to the `formatter` argument. The reason why the sample codes show what looks like the wrong usage of `format` is because the formatter actually calls the function (or in this case a method) with an dictionary argument. So it turns into something like this:

```
d = {x:123} # this is just to show what d is, it's not part of the code
"Value: {x:.0f}".format(d)
```

The argument is added to it. But to modify the contents of the dictionary, you need to use a lambda that accepts a dict and then unpacks it with neccessary modification. We take the value by the key `"x"` and add 70 to it.
Those stars before `d` are to form the dictionary from the given keyword arguments. So a function `f(**d)` when called like this: `f(a=1, b=2, c=3)` will have a dictionary `d` with the `key:value` pairs from the arguments: `{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}`. This allows the function to accept any amount of arguments and have them all nicely stored in a dictionary for you to use.

Comment: thank you @Leva7 but it does not work, I get the error: `TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'label'`

Comment: @MrPedru22 check it out, I think this might be correct now.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you're calling format improperly. You need to specify what it is that you're formatting. Here's an example:

```
val = 7
out = '{:0f}'.format(val)
```

That yields:

```
'7.000000'
```

If you're trying to use that to add 70, you could try this:

```
val = 7
out = str(float('{:0f}'.format(val)) + 70)
```

which yields:

```
'77.0'
```

Finally, turning that into a lambda function:

```
formatter = lambda x: str(float('{:0f}'.format(x)) + 70)
formatter(7)
>> '77.0'
```

Hope that's what you're after.

Comment: thank you @stackunderflow but it does not work either, I get the same error as in @Leva7 answer: `TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'label'`

Comment: @MrPedru22: I think this might be your issue. Note that a lambda function can be treated as any regular function. In the following case, 'x' is the expected input parameter:
`a = lambda x: x + 1`
and if you then attempt to call the function a on the value '2', it should return '3'
`a(2)
>>3`
Now, if you attempt to name the input, it may crash if it doesn't match.
`a(label = 2)
TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'label'`
There are two solutions. The first is to just make the function:
`a = lambda label: label + 1`
or just pass the value in instead of labeling it:
`a(2)
>3`